# How can I set the execution strategy of a DbContext generated with Database First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6's Database First migrations to auto-generate a `DbContext` and a set of entities for a database. This database changes frequently, so the migration needs to be re-run every once in a while to keep it up to date, removing any changes that were made manually to the `DbContext`. To give the `DbContext` the standard retry logic, I would like to make it use `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`.

I have had success so far dynamically creating a class, using reflection, that inherits from the `DbContext` and is configured via `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute` to use the execution strategy. This seems a bit backhanded, however - is there a cleaner, more obvious way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.  I added a new class:

```
namespace SharedTools
{
    public class AzureDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public AzureDBConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
        }
    }
}
```

Then... in my web.config, in the entity framework configuration section:

```
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
         <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

I just added this attribute:

```
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="SharedTools.AzureDBConfiguration, SharedTools">
         <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

Debugger is hit in the DBConfiguration before anything else.  It seems to have done the trick and no reflection.  I did confirm it by putting a breakpoint in the constructor of the "entities" DBContext object, and exploring it through the watch window.  Specifically, looking at the non-public members of the Configuration object, there is a property on the _internalContext called AppConfig, and you can see the ConfigurationTypeName listed there.